Msteams bot custom tab sso failing with error code 2605 ServerTemporarilyUnavailable
we have msteams bot with custom tab in it. We use msal.js for automated sso as per this doc. Since today morning, we are suddenly getting the error:
{"Description":"(pii)","Domain":"com.microsoft.oneauth","ErrorCode":"2605","Message":"The server is temporarily unavailable","SystemErrorCode":"3399614469","Tag":"7q6ci","Type":"OneAuth","additional_query_parameters_count":"1","all_error_tags":"7q6ci|7q6ci","api_error_code":"3399614469","api_error_context":"(pii)","api_error_tag":"7q6ci","api_name":"AcquireTokenSilently","api_status_code":"StatusInternal::ServerTemporarilyUnavailable","auth_flow":"Broker","authority_type":"AAD","authorization_type":"WindowsIntegratedAuth","broker_app_used":"true","broker_error_location":"7q6ci","client_id":"1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264","correlation_id":"39b75d91-dcc0-48c4-82f2-7e8f880a2299","is_successful":"false","msal_version":"1.1.0+00747db6","original_authority":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/513294a0-3e20-41b2-a970-6d30bf1546fa","read_token":"ID","request_duration":"484","request_eligible_for_broker":"true","start_time":"2024-06-24T08:34:35.000Z","stop_time":"2024-06-24T08:34:35.000Z","wam_telemetry":"{\"ui_visible\":false,\"scope\":\"api://chatteron.io/7313ffbd-0d2f-4ee7-85d8-ae2cff842ebc/.default offline_access openid profile\",\"redirect_uri\":\"ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264\",\"provider_id\":\"https://login.windows.net\",\"oauth_error_code\":\"authentication_failed\",\"device_join\":\"dj\",\"correlation_id\":\"{39b75d91-dcc0-48c4-82f2-7e8f880a2299}\",\"client_id\":\"1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264\",\"cache_event_count\":0,\"broker_version\":\"10.0.22621.3672\",\"authority\":\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/513294a0-3e20-41b2-a970-6d30bf1546fa\",\"api_error_code\":-894893983,\"account_join_on_start\":\"primary\",\"account_join_on_end\":\"primary\",\"silent_code\":0,\"silent_bi_sub_code\":0,\"silent_message\":\"\",\"silent_status\":0,\"is_cached\":0}","was_request_throttled":"false"}

Can someone help with the issue? looks like an issue from microsoft backend.
We have tried to logout and relogging in the user, if there is any token cache issue. Also reinstalling the manifest to the user.
